# How to pass url as an input in retrofit (JSON)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I have to send this URL as input in retrofit POST method

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/admob-app-id-1676370691.appspot.com/o/imagaine%2Fimages%2Ff59893d66a6e12be%2Fimagaine.jpg?alt=media&token=35483f86-ee72-4831-96c8-296c543dc0ec
```

But when I sent the request the URL became like the link below.

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/admob-app-id-1676370691.appspot.com/o/imagaine%2Fimages%2Ff59893d66a6e12be%2Fimagaine.jpg?alt\u003dmedia\u0026token\u003d35483f86-ee72-4831-96c8-296c543dc0ec
```

What can I do to make the link not changeable when the request is sent?

```
val finalInput =
            JSONObject("{\"uuid\":${uuid},\"image_url\":\"${url}\"}")
val retroService = RetroInstance().getInstance(randomUrl)?.create(ApiService::class.java)
val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
callPostResponse = retroService?.getPostResponse(
            mapper.readValue(finalInput.toString()),
        )
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: @Ivo updated the code. Please check